# How to add data in the dat file to mysql database properly

Tags: mysql

I have around 500k data in a tes_data.dat.I want to add the data in that file to a table in MySQL DB i have been looking how to do that but i couldn't find any, if someone can help me by saying how to do this or giving any links or something will be really helpful.
this is how my table structure

> `mysql> CREATE TABLE sample_test_datatwo(lat FLOAT, lon FLOAT, day INT,` `mon INT,`
> `pressure INT, Temp FLOAT, RH FLOAT, U FLOAT, V FLOAT);`
> `Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.60 sec)`

mysql> describe sample_test_datatwo;

```
+----------+-------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type  | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+-------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| lat      | float | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| lon      | float | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| day      | int   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| mon      | int   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| pressure | int   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Temp     | float | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| RH       | float | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| U        | float | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| V        | float | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+-------+------+-----+---------+-------+

9 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

Sample of file

```
    lat   lon    day mon  pressure  Temp      RH        U        V
  5.00   60.00  01  01   100000    298.22    79.75    -3.48    -4.64
  5.00   60.25  01  01   100000    298.24    79.85    -3.42    -4.57
  5.00   60.50  01  01   100000    298.29    79.59    -3.36    -4.46
  5.00   60.75  01  01   100000    298.33    79.58    -3.30    -4.36
  5.00   61.00  01  01   100000    298.38    79.23    -3.27    -4.24
  5.00   61.25  01  01   100000    298.42    79.22    -3.27    -4.11
```

### EDIT

i did added the data from file to database using the LOAD DATA statement
This is how i did

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/mypc/Desktop/Sample.dat' 
INTO TABLE sample_test_datatwo  
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '  '
    LINES  TERMINATED BY '\n' -- or \r\n 
    IGNORE 1 LINES;

    Query OK, 512676 rows affected, 65535 warnings (59.90 sec)
    Records: 512676  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 2027862
```

But what happend is tha the data in database is mismatched with data in the file

this is data in database that i loaded from the file

> 

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM sample_test_datatwo LIMIT 5;
+------+------+------+------+----------+--------+------+--------+------+
| lat  | lon  | day  | mon  | pressure | Temp   | RH   | U      | V    |
+------+------+------+------+----------+--------+------+--------+------+
|    0 |    5 |   60 |    1 |        1 | 100000 |    0 | 298.22 |    0 |
|    0 |    5 |   60 |    1 |        1 | 100000 |    0 | 298.24 |    0 |
|    0 |    5 |   61 |    1 |        1 | 100000 |    0 | 298.29 |    0 |
|    0 |    5 |   61 |    1 |        1 | 100000 |    0 | 298.33 |    0 |
|    0 |    5 |   61 |    1 |        1 | 100000 |    0 | 298.38 |    0 |
+------+------+------+------+----------+--------+------+--------+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

i don't know what did gone wrong here

Comment: *I have around 500k data in a tes_data.dat.* In what format? *I want to add the data in that file to a table in MySQL DB* Show its CREATE TABLE.

Comment: What is the format of the data? Are you going to upload the table reading the data form this file or you just want to add the whole chunk of data in text or csv?

Comment: @PrabirGhosh i mean i want to add the datas in that file to mysql like a with same format like that file by format i mean the same column name and all

Comment: @Akina the file format is dat

Comment: Do not confuse inner data format and file extension.

Comment: @Akina oh sorry, the inner data format is (lat FLOAT, lon, FLOAT, day INT, mon INT, pressure INT, Temp FLOAT, RH FLOAT, U FLOAT, V FLOAT)

Comment: Add into the question text: complete CREATE TABLE script for destination table; a sample of file content (3-5 rows). As properly formatted text, not as screenshots.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Without seeing how the file looks like, it's impossible to tell you how to parse it. Additionally, do you plan to use any other tools to parse the data, or are you searching for a pure MySQL solution?

Comment: @Akina i have updated my question with sample data

Comment: @NicoHaase i was looking for something like LOAD DATA INFILE but now i am doing like using python looping through each line of the file and executing insert into query.

Comment: Use [LOAD DATA Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) and import the data from the file into the table. Check what is inter-columns delimiter (tabular or a lot of spaces) and specify according `FIELDS TERMINATED BY`. Check what is the linebreak and specify according `LINES TERMINATED BY`.

Comment: *i am doing like using python looping through each line of the file and executing insert into query.* Simply execute LOAD DATA - MySQl will read the whole file, iterate over its lines, parse them and put all data into rows. After this (one!) statement execution the whole file data is imported if no error occures during the execution.

Comment: @Akina yeak thank you i thought LOAD DATA only works for txt file, i will try your solution

Comment: *i thought LOAD DATA only works for txt file* This is true. But do not confuse - it works "for text file" and not "for a file with .txt extension". I.e. inner content, not file extension is taken into account.

Comment: @Akina I have succefully loded the data from file to DB but the data in data bases is mismatched. this is was my query i executed ```LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/mypc/Desktop/Sample.dat' 
INTO TABLE sample_test_datatwo  
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '  '
    LINES  TERMINATED BY '\n' -- or \r\n 
    IGNORE 1 LINES;```

Comment: Please add all clarification **to your question** by editing it. This should contain your approaches, and the problems you are facing

Comment: @NicoHaase i will update my question

Comment: @NicoHaase I updated my question it will be really helpful if anyone can figure out what did i wrong here.

Comment: The example-data is copy-pasted directly from the source? In the source the lines also start with x spaces? Also, the amount of spaces seem to differ between values, correct? Between `lat` and `lon` it's 3 and between `Temp`and `RH` it's 4.

Comment: Have you tried replacing the blocks of spaces with another separator via a text-editor?

Comment: @Sam020 yes it is directly copy pasted no i haven't tried replacing the blocks

Answer (score 2):

Your data is fixed-length, not CSV. This is a problem.

You specify the columns terminator as 2 spaces. And delimiters in source row are treated as:

```
    lat   lon    day mon  pressure  Temp      RH        U        V     -- header
  5.00   60.00  01  01   100000    298.22    79.75    -3.48    -4.64   -- values
11    22      33  44  55       6677      8899     AABB     CCDD        -- delims
```

The simplest way to solve is to load a line into a variable then parse:

```sql
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/mypc/Desktop/Sample.dat'  
INTO TABLE sample_test_datatwo  
IGNORE 1 LINES
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ''                                -- the whole row is one column
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(@string)                                              -- load the whole line
SET lat      = TRIM(SUBSTRING(@string FROM  1 FOR 6)), -- extract separate values
    lon      = TRIM(SUBSTRING(@string FROM  8 FOR 7)),
    day      = TRIM(SUBSTRING(@string FROM 16 FOR 3)),
    mon      = TRIM(SUBSTRING(@string FROM 20 FOR 3)),
    pressure = TRIM(SUBSTRING(@string FROM 24 FOR 8)),
    Temp     = TRIM(SUBSTRING(@string FROM 33 FOR 9)),
    RH       = TRIM(SUBSTRING(@string FROM 43 FOR 8)),
    U        = TRIM(SUBSTRING(@string FROM 52 FOR 8)),
    V        = TRIM(SUBSTRING(@string FROM 61 FOR 8));
```

Adjust offsets and lengths for separate columns if needed.